# Qual diferença entre where e having?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-select

Fazendo alguns testes em uma base de dados que em MySQL, percebi que:

```
SELECT * From client WHERE uuid = '1kvsg4oracxq'
```

retorna o mesmo resultado que:

```
SELECT * From client HAVING uuid = '1kvsg4oracxq'
```

Qual exatamente a real diferença entre `where` e `having`?

Comment: [Link interessante](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/04/sql-server-definition-comparison-and-difference-between-having-and-where-clause/) HAVING especifica uma condição de busca para um grupo ou uma função agregada usada em uma consulta SQL

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ambos funcionam como se fossem um `if`, ou seja, filtram linhas do banco de dados.

O `WHERE` funciona direto na linha, já o `HAVING` funciona em resultados de agregadores de linhas, o mais usado é com o `GROUP BY`.

Pesquisando concluí que realmente é esperado que o seu uso sem um agregador funciona como um `WHERE`, não é uma coincidência, apesar de ser uma liberalidade, não há nada na especificação que diga que deva ser assim. De acordo com o Jefferson Almeida em comentário abaixo, fazer assim não é portável entre o padrão SQL.

Tem quem prefira até evitá-lo, usando *subquery* e outros mecanismos, aplicando o `WHERE` nesse resultado.

É realmente importante perguntar já que esse é um dos casos que funcionar pode não ser o certo, embora eu não consiga imagina que problema possa causar nesse caso. Já usar `WHERE` quando quer filtrar o agregado não funciona.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Segundo o link que eu postei no comentário, quando Group By não está presente, Having se comporta como um Where, acho que é isso que acontece huahua

Comment: @ArturoTemplário sim, faz todo sentido, mas eu quero ter algo mais certo.

Comment: No SQL Server, por exemplo, não funciona.

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida tem certeza?

Comment: @bigown acabei de testar, da a seguinte mensagem: "A coluna 'XXXX' é inválida na cláusula HAVING porque não está contida em uma função de agregação nem na cláusula GROUP BY."

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida a coluna tem que ser exatamente o nome ou alias que vc definiu no SELECT: `SELECT COUNT(CustomerID), Country
FROM Customers
GROUP BY Country
HAVING COUNT(CustomerID) > 5;` [Documentacao](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)

Comment: @Everson estamos falando sem o uso do `Group By` e utilizando uma coluna dentro do `Having`

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida having só pode ser usado com group by.  _"A cláusula HAVING determina uma condição de busca para um grupo ou um conjunto de registros, definindo critérios para limitar os resultados obtidos a partir do agrupamento de registros. É importante lembrar que essa cláusula só pode ser usada em parceria com GROUP BY."_ [Fonte](http://www.devmedia.com.br/exemplos-com-group-by-e-com-a-clausula-having-totalizando-dados-sql-server-2008-parte-2/19839)

Comment: @Everson primeiro, essa sua afirmação está errada, a clausula `Having` pode sim ser usada sem o `Group By` em algumas situações. Segundo eu comentei justamente o que você disse, que se vc usar ela sem o `Group By` vai gerar o erro q eu informei, isso no SQL Serve, porém até mesmo no SQL Serve ela pode ser usada sem o Group

Comment: @Everson pode até ser, mas tem um sinais vermelhos nesse texto, não sei se a fonte é boa.

Comment: @bigown no SOen existe esse [Topico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924896/having-without-group-by) , com necessidade de um agrupador

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/57445/41

Comment: @bigown `having 1 = 1` não é "funcional", pois essa condição não interfere no resultado e se remover da na mesma. Seria mesma coisa que `where 1=1`, e trocando por `where 1 = 2` não retorna nada devido a cláusula ser falsa. A única utilização que funciona é com agrupadores que podem variar o resultado.

Answer (score 8):

A diferença é que o HAVING é utilizado juntamente com o GROUP BY, exemplo:

```
SELECT a.id, COUNT(a.id) qtde FROM sua_tabela a
WHERE a.um_campo_da_sua_tabela = 'um_valor_qualquer'
GROUP BY a.categoria
HAVING qtde > 5
```

Nessa consulta acima, o WHERE esta fazendo o papel normal dele, que é filtrar a consulta. O GROUP BY esta agrupando os resultados de acordo com a categoria. E o HAVING esta filtrando o campo qtde.

Comment: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/548857-ajuda-com-sql-count-case-when-having/?do=findComment&comment=2191595

Comment: Não explicitamente o group by, mas estruturas de agrupamento. Você pode ver [nesse topico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924896/having-without-group-by)

Answer (score 6):

A diferença fundamental entre entre as duas cláusulas é que `Where` realiza a filtragem nas tabelas de origem como primeiro passo da consulta (query), enquanto `Having` realiza a filtragem na tabela resultante, como último passo da consulta. Dessa diferença fundamental, derivam as demais diferenças de especificação e de funcionalidade entre as duas cláusulas, em especial:

1. Referências às variáveis;
2. Utilização na junção de tabelas (join);
3. Filtragem com base em agregadores;

**1. Referências às variáveis:**

Na cláusula `Where` os nomes das variáveis utilizadas como condições da filtragem devem ser iguais aos nomes da tabela de origem. Já na cláusula `Having` os nomes das variáveis devem ser iguais aos nomes da tabela resultante.  No exemplo citado, suponha que você mude o nome da variável de `uuid` para `usuario`. Na cláusula `Where` você terá que utilizar o nome antigo; na cláusula `Having` você utilizará o nome novo:

```
SELECT uuid as usuario, password as senha  From client WHERE uuid = '1kvsg4oracxq';

SELECT uuid as usuario, password as senha From client HAVING usuario = '1kvsg4oracxq';
```

**2. Junção de tabelas:**

A cláusula `Where` é bastante útil na junção de tabelas. Ao filtrar diretamente na tabela de origem, ela torna mais ágil a junção de grandes bases de dados:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* From client as t1
LEFT JOIN company as t2 on t1.comp_id = t2.comp_id
WHERE t1.uuid = '1kvsg4oracxq';
```

Repare que caso a variável `uuid` esteja presente em mais de uma tabela de origem, você precisa fazer referência à tabela na qual será realizada a filtragem, no exemplo acima é a t1 (ou client).

Você ainda poderia obter o mesmo resultado com a cláusula `Having`, mas a um custo computacional muito maior. Nessa segunda opção, o software vai juntar todos os casos das duas tabelas primeiro e depois realizar a filtragem. Se suas tabelas forem grandes, levará muito mais tempo, além de estar sujeito a limitações de espaço de gravação dos arquivos temporários.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* From client 
LEFT JOIN company on t1.comp_id = t2.comp_id
HAVING uuid = '1kvsg4oracxq';
```

Quando utilizamos a cláusula `Having`, não faz sentido indicar a tabela de origem da variável, pois a filtragem é realizada na tabela final (resultante).

**3. Filtragem com base em agregadores:**

Por fim, a principal, e já citada, funcionalidade da cláusula `Having` é a filtragem com base em agregadores e novas variáveis produzidas na consulta. Uma vez que cláusula `Where` realiza a filtragem nas tabelas originais, ela não tem capacidade de fazer referência aos agregadores criados na própria query. Já a clausula `Having`, por filtrar na última etapa da consulta, tem a capacidade de interagir com elementos criados durante a consulta.

A cláusula `Having` em conjunto com `Group by`  é muito útil para eliminar duplicatas condicionalmente. Por exemplo, se cada cliente de sua tabela tiver muitos registros e cada registro tem uma data diferente (por exemplo, na variável de data `DT_LOG`), você pode obter uma nova tabela apenas com o registro mais recente (ou o valor máximo de `DT_LOG`) para cada cliente:

```
CREATE TABLE LOG_MAIS_RECENTE as
SELECT DISTINCT * From client 
GROUP BY uuid
HAVING DT_LOG = MAX(DT_LOG);
```