# Usando dados de um select dentro de outro?

Tags: mysql, query, select, inner

Duas tabelas `tbl_orcamento` e `tbl_itens` a tabela orcamentos possui uma coluna com os seguintes status.

```
1 = orcamento aprovado
2 = ordem de compra emitida
3 = ordem de compra aprovada
```

A `tbl_itens` possui algumas colunas vou listar as que serão utilizadas na consulta.

- id_tbl_orcamento
- data_recebimento
- n_nf_recebida

e consulta que estou tentando fazer é saber se todos os ítens do pedido chegaram, a forma como estou usando está abaixo.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_orcamento
INNER JOIN tbl_itens ON tbl_orcamento.id = tbl_itens.id_tbl_orcamento
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(q.id) / t.total * 100 FROM tbl_itens q, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM tbl_itens 
WHERE id_tbl_orcamento = tbl_orcamento.id ) t 
WHERE id_tbl_orcamento = tbl_orcamento.id AND n_nf_recebida != 0) = 100.0000
```

Creio que no segundo SELECT a instrução não esteja entendendo o `id` **id_tbl_orcamento = tbl_orcamento_id**, existe uma forma de passar a variavel da primeira instrução para a segunda.

Este é o `SELECT` interno correspondente ao `WHERE` principal

```
SELECT COUNT(q.id) / t.total * 100 FROM tbl_itens q, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM tbl_itens 
WHERE id_tbl_orcamento = tbl_orcamento.id ) t 
WHERE id_tbl_orcamento = tbl_orcamento.id AND n_nf_recebida != 0
```

Que deve verificar se os itens referente ao pedido possui numero de nf, e caso seja igual a zero ainda esta pendente então o pedido estára incompleto, caso todos estejam com numero de nf o valor será 100 e assim satisfazer a query.

Minha dúvida está nesta linha da `QUERY`

> id_tbl_orcamento = tbl_orcamento.id

Pois não estou passando um valor, estou tentando pegar dinamicamente.
Dessa forma a `QUERY` funciona.

> id_tbl_orcamento = '123'

Comment: Você recebe algum erro? Não entendi o problema

Comment: Recebo NULL, mas se fizer a consulta interna informando um id válido recebo o valor porcentual de ítens recebido e caso tudo tenha sido recebido recebo 100.0000

Comment: Mas você recebe `NULL` em qual consulta? pode especificar melhor o seu problema na pergunta?

Comment: Recebo null na instrucao da pergunta. Estou desconfiado que o segundo select não está recendo o numero do id da tabela tbl_orcamento.

Comment: Editei a pergunta espero que de pra entender

Comment: Tenta fazer assim: `SELECT * FROM tbl_orcamento a
INNER JOIN tbl_itens b ON a.id = b.id_tbl_orcamento
WHERE (
 SELECT SUM(IF(a1.n_nf_recebida != 0, 1, 0)) / COUNT(a1.id) * 100
 FROM tbl_itens a1
 WHERE a1.id_tbl_orcamento = a.id
) = 100;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado usando `HAVING` a query comparando as variáveis `noc` e `nocs`

A query ficou da seguinte forma

```
SELECT *, COUNT(tbl_itens.data_recebido) as noc, COUNT(tbl_itens.n_nf_recebida) as nocs 
FROM tbl_orcamento
INNER JOIN tbl_itens ON tbl_orcamento.id = tbl_itens.id_tbl_orcamento
WHERE tbl_orcamento.status = 1
GROUP BY tbl_itens.id_tbl_orcamento
HAVING noc = nocs // compara os valores se forem iguais os itens foram recebidos
ORDER BY tbl_orcamento.id ASC
```

Como queria apenas exibir os pedidos que forma 100% recebidos, mas caso queia mostrar apenas os dados que ainda possuem ítens pendentes de recebimento pode usar o `HAVING` da seguinte forma.

```
HAVING noc != nocs //dessa forma ele carrega apenas os dados que ainda possuem ítens pendente de recebimento.
```

Lembre-se o `HAVING` precisa ficar após `GROUP BY`, nessa forma como demonstrada.

Tem uma resposta muito boa aqui no SO que explica o funcionamento do `having` [Veja Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211794/qual-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-where-e-having).