# Por que não é possível usar um "alias" na cláusula WHERE no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, where

Eu preciso usar um *alias* na cláusula `WHERE`, mas continua me dizendo que é uma "coluna desconhecida".

Eu preciso selecionar registros que tenham uma classificação maior que X. A classificação é calculada como o seguinte *alias*:

```
sum(reviews.rev_avaliacao)/count(reviews.rev_id) as avg_avaliacao
```

Porém dessa forma ele resulta o erro citado acima:

```
WHERE avg_avaliacao > 10
```

Já com o uso do `HAVING` é possível contornar essa situação:

```
HAVING avg_avaliacao > 10
```

Por que isso é possível?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211794/8063

Comment: Acredito que é até duplicata, pois a resposta do Maniero responde esta pergunta (não explicitamente). `where` é aplicado diretamente sobre cada registro, não possuindo a coluna em questão; enquanto `having` é aplicado sobre o resultado, já existindo a *coluna* definida pelo *alias*.

Comment: Eu li essa discussão, se você perceber, pelo menos na época eles falam que o `HAVING` normalmente é usado com um `GROUP BY` e sem ele, o `HAVING` basicamente exerceria a função de um `WHERE`

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss pelo que entendi ele quer saber o porquê, e lá não tem.

Comment: Acredito que não seja uma boa pratica utilizar o `HAVING` sem o `GROUP BY` mas de todo modo funciona(mas pode não ser o certo), só queria saber exatamente o porque. @AndersonCarlosWoss entendi, queria saber exatamente isso, se for de fato o que acontece.

Comment: @PHPatrick Mas você está utilizando funções de agregação para somar e contar, você não está utilizando o `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Não estou usando o `GROUP BY` no MySQL isso é possível

Comment: Para complementar melhor estou usando como base uma outra pergunta do SOen, porém lá o foco é outro e eles não explicam porque com o `HAVING` é possível fazer isso.

Pergunta do SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O *alias* é criado durante a execução do `SELECT`. Ao contrário do que possa parecer intuitivo, afinal esta cláusula do comando vem sempre antes de tudo, o `WHERE` é executado sempre antes, então ele escolhe quais as linhas serão capturadas nessa consulta e depois ele verá quais colunas serão usadas para produzir o resultado final. Mas isso por si só não é um impedimento técnico. Acontece que há casos que esse o `SELECT` é executado para produzir um resultado que faça sentido para o *alias* existir. Então você acaba entrando em um problema do ovo e da galinha, para fazer o `WHERE`, precisa executar o `SELECT` e para executar o `SELECT` precisa executar o `WHERE`.

Por alguma razão acharam que o `HAVING` deveria executar depois do `SELECT`. Obviamente que ele deve ser depois do `WHERE`, acho que isto não tem dúvida, mas poderia ser antes do `SELECT`. Isto não faz parte do padrão e até onde sei só o MySQL permite. Eles acharam útil e que valia o esforço, e ele não teria o mesmo problema. Não há uma situação que um depende do outro para acontecer. Pelo menos acharam que não.

NO exemplo a contagem só ocorre depois de todo o `WHERE` rodar. Já o `HAVING` ocorre ao final de todo o `WHERE`, e se o `WHERE` terminou ele pode executar o `SELECT`. Tendo o `SELECT` tem o *alias*, então pode usar no `HAVING`.

Parou pra pensar que ele está te dando o mesmo resultado, mas talvez não seja tão eficiente? Não digo nesse caso, mas em alguns isso pode acontecer, o `WHERE` é diferente do `HAVING` (você está usando um mecanismo para analisar agrupamentos como análise de linhas), mesmo dando o mesmo resultado ele tem um compromisso diferente. Veja se demorou o mesmo e mande explicar a consulta para ver se o esforço é o mesmo.

Se você perguntam se deveria deixar usar o *alias* no `WHERE` onde não tiver uma dependência, eu diria que se o analisador entender que não há problema, deveria deixar usar.

Acho que não se esforçaram muito porque convenhamos que o *alias* simples que não tem como causar problema é só uma comodidade não muito importante e tem lá seu ponto negativo também para a legibilidade (assim como tem positivo pro mesmo aspecto).

Ordem normal de execução (MySQL muda um pouco):

- FROM
- WHERE
- GROUP BY
- HAVING
- SELECT
- ORDER BY

[Documentação do SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (tem mais cláusulas).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: De fato o uso do `HAVING` dessa forma é possível apenas no MySQL. Porém não fazia ideia da ordem de aplicação das cláusulas, e que isso impactaria no resultado final. Acredito que o essencial em casos como esse seria usar uma subquery, já que como você citou o `HAVING` tem como foco análise de agrupamentos. Excelente resposta, queria saber precisamente como acontecia esse processo.