# Como "chamar" uma coluna em PDO

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, pdo

Eu tenho um sistema de procura em PHP onde uso uma query em PDO com várias tabelas

Eu coloquei as colunas e dei um nome a elas do género:

```
SELECT a.cod_aluno AS ID
```

Mas ao realizar a procura no site, me dá um erro no PHP dizendo que desconhece a coluna ID, e o erro dá-se na linha da query, na condição **WHERE**.

Tem algum erro que eu não saiba, uma vírgula ou aspas?

QUERY:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT a.nome AS Aluno, a.Cod_Aluno AS ID, t.Cod_Turma AS Turma, p.nome AS Professor FROM aluno a, turma t, disc_turma d, professor p WHERE a.Cod_Turma = t.Cod_Turma AND t.Cod_Turma = d.Cod_Turma AND d.Cod_Professor = p.cod_professor AND ID LIKE :ref');
```

Comment: _"SELECT DISTINCT a.nome AS Aluno, a.Cod_Aluno AS ID, t.Cod_Turma AS Turma, p.nome AS Professor FROM aluno a, turma t, disc_turma d, professor p WHERE a.Cod_Turma = t.Cod_Turma AND t.Cod_Turma = d.Cod_Turma AND d.Cod_Professor = p.cod_professor AND **a.Cod_Aluno** LIKE :ref"_  Coloque dessa forma e veja se o erro some

Comment: Você pode ver uma dúvida parecida aqui: [Por que não é possível usar um "alias" na cláusula WHERE no MySQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/391262/por-que-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-poss%C3%ADvel-usar-um-alias-na-cl%C3%A1usula-where-no-mysql)

Comment: Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A clausula `WHERE` é executada antes do `SELECT`, portanto não se utiliza *alias* em `WHERE`

*"SELECT DISTINCT a.nome AS Aluno, a.Cod_Aluno AS ID, t.Cod_Turma AS Turma, p.nome AS Professor FROM aluno a, turma t, disc_turma d, professor p WHERE a.Cod_Turma = t.Cod_Turma AND t.Cod_Turma = d.Cod_Turma AND d.Cod_Professor = p.cod_professor AND **a.Cod_Aluno** LIKE :ref"*

Coloque dessa forma e veja se o erro some

Você pode ver uma dúvida parecida aqui: [Por que não é possível usar um "alias" na cláusula WHERE no MySQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/391262/por-que-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-poss%C3%ADvel-usar-um-alias-na-cl%C3%A1usula-where-no-mysql)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, valeu!!!